# Kentico 9 bizform file upload validation

Tags: kentico

I'm looking for a method to limit the file size on a upload as part of a form. The form builder validation rules having nothing for file size.

I came across this article: https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-validate-the-size-of-uploaded-file-in-bizform but i was worried it may cause other issues since its tagged v5.5.

Can this be done via a macro expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Kentico Marketplace](http://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/inline-controls/file-upload-w-size-limit), there is a form control which will do this already for you.  Just import it and start using it.

If it isn't working for your version, download it, review the code and make modifications to your version accordingly.  Cloning an existing control and adding the additional code will do what you're looking for if a different version.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running 9 with hotfix 30. I'll let you know. Cheers!

Comment: Can i just add the Custom folder and files, once i remove the .export extension and then build the solution? The import is running as smooth as i had hoped.

Comment: If you imported properly, you should have checked the Import files and folders and it would have done it for you.  If you didn't unzip the package and take those 2 files out and remove the .export extension as you mentioned and copy them to the same directory you see in the zip file to your website.

Comment: I got it. Even after converting to a web app, i still had to manually move the files into CMSFormControls. Next step for this is some localization of the error messages. Then looking at a file uploading spinner. But one thing at a time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could customize/create the new one form control - UploadControl. You can inspire in **CSMFormControls > Media > UploadControl.ascx.cs**. There is

```
CMS.Base.Web.UI.Uploader uploader
```

property which has field called

```
HttpPostedFile PostedFile
```

which has property

```
 //
 // Summary:
 //     Gets the size of an uploaded file, in bytes.
 //
 // Returns:
 //     The file length, in bytes.
 public int ContentLength { get; }
```

I think you could validate depending on this property.

You can learn more about form controls in general [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-form-controls/example-developing-custom-form-controls).

Comment: My worry was impacting other cms desk uploaders. I'm going to try Brenden's idea before i start down this path.